# Is there a way to use Firebase Dynamic Links in Flutter Web Application?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a production flutter app and I am using firebase dynamic links in it, now I am trying to create a web version of my app but my dynamic links are not working on the web, it takes me to a page that says "Dynamic Link Not Found". The official [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) package does not show 'Web' in the supported platforms section.
Is there any workaround for this situation?

Although I tried adding the ofl/ifl/afl parameters manually, but that didn't work either.